# class of a DOM and jQUery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I sometimes see that there is something like this:

```
<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star 1"/>


<input name="star2" type="radio" class="star 2"/>
```

is it possible in jQuery to let one class to handle these two class? Because basically they have the same parent class, which is star? If it is possible, how can I do that? Using regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can select both of them with `$('.star')`. What you may have been trying to refer to is [*starts with attribute selector*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Also, I doubt that `1` is a valid class name.

Comment: I actually tried to find a definition in the standards about what constitutes a valid class name, but in the HTML4 specification they only have rules for name and id attributes. The class attribute is simply defined as a "cdata-list" (i.e., CDATA), and the only restriction seems to be that multiple classes is separated by whitespace.

Comment: @Emil I looked too, and couldn't find it.

Comment: It's still sane to try to stick to conventional naming standard, though :-)

Comment: The class attribute contains class *names*, an HTML name must start with a letter (it has the same constraints as an id).